# Camera/SurfaceView app returns android icon not emulator checkerboard image

Tags: android

I'm using the android SDK in Eclipse on Linux.  I've used the code at itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/androidCamera101.pdf to write an app to store an image captured through the camera onto SD card (there are various examples of this around). It works ok except that the image returned by the camera is not what's on the preview surface. Instead of getting the checkerboard image I expect, I get different versions of the android icon depending on which version of target I choose. If I render the image to an ImageView this is confirmed as it's the same as on the SD card.

Any ideas

Ta

J

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the emulator docs I found this:

Emulator Limitations
In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:

No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.

No support for USB connections

No support for camera/video capture (input).

No support for device-attached headphones

No support for determining connected state

No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state

No support for determining SD card insert/eject

No support for Bluetooth

↑ Go to top 
Except as noted, this content is licensed under Apache 2.0. For details and restrictions, see the Content License. 
Android 2.2 r1 - 23 Sep 2010 11:49 
Site Terms of Service - Privacy Policy - Brand Guidelines

This might explain it.